# Why can't YouTube, Audacity, Tartini and PulseAudio all get along?

Tags: 12.04, sound, pulseaudio, youtube

(This is on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with all the latest updates applied.)

One audio application I use a lot is [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/), both as an audio player and as a recorder, usually with the cheapest headsets I can find.

I also use YouTube a lot (i.e. Flash in Firefox).

The two work together pretty well: e.g. I can play audio from both simultaneously.

Recently, I started to use another audio application: [Tartini](http://miracle.otago.ac.nz/tartini/).
Thanks to [Jeremy Salwen's](https://github.com/jeremysalwen/tartini-debian) and [Jevon Longdell's efforts](https://github.com/jevonlongdell/tartini), it compiled without any problems, and after getting OpenGL to work, it runs, too. So I expected it to mix in with the other two:

[image: YouTube, Tartini and Audacity running side by side]

but it doesn't. Initially, it wouldn't play any audio *at all*.

Somehow, I found out that in Ubuntu's "sound settings"

[image: Ubuntu Sound Settings]

I had to select 'Digital Output (S/PDIF)' before audio played back with Tartini would be audible - but this mutes YouTube and Audacity. I don't want to need to switch between 'Digital' and non-'Digital' outputs depending on the application I happen to be using. I don't care whether 'outputs' (whatever they are) are 'Digital' (whatever that means); I just want sound produced by an application to play whenever I ask it to, whether or not some other application happens to be playing or recording sound at that time.

Somehow, I found out that there is an application called 'paprefs' that has an option to enable 'simultaneous output on all local sound cards', whatever that means, so I installed it and enabled that option:

[image: paprefs simultaneous output option]

This gave me a new option in the Sound Settings:

[image: Ubuntu Sound Settings with new option]

and after I selected that, Audacity and Tartini would both play audio, not simultaneously, but whichever was started first.  At least, that was the case for a short while; then the previous behavior returned.

After rebooting, the new behavior was restored: I can now play sound from Audacity and/or YouTube, simultaneously if I wish; or from Tartini; but never from Audacity and Tartini, or YouTube and Tartini, at the same time. However, the Ubuntu Sound Settings and pavucontrol are no longer available: pavucontrol claims it can't connect to PulseAudio:

[image: pavucontrol cannot connect to PulseAudio]

and indeed, nothing related to pulse is running on my system.

Questions:

1. What on earth is going on? How do I find out?
2. Can YouTube and Tartini play sound at the same time?
3. ... while PulseAudio is running?
4. How? / Why not?
5. How does my audio processing hardware come into this?

`lspci` says I have a `00:1f.5 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation 82801EB/ER (ICH5/ICH5R) AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 02)`

Comment: Does Tartini not appear under the `Applications` tab in sound settings?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Neither do Firefox or Audacity, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this won't help you, but I had similar problem - my Tuxguitar didn't make any sound while Youtube was on. I solved it by installing Fluidsynth and Qsynth, then making some random changes in Qsynth (and then Tuxgutar) settings.

I found it (also with instructions) here, on the bottom of the page.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2132761

Comment: I doubt this is related - your question seems to be about MIDI playing - but I'll try it anyway, thanks.

Comment: Well, after installing `tuxguitar` (which also installs `tuxguitar-alsa`), it produced the message `/dev/sequencer: No such file or directory` and remained silent; I fixed that under Tools->Settings->Sound by switching MIDI output to 'Timidity port 0'. If your problem was the same, I don't think it is related to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a partial answer by Jan Schmidt [here](https://youtu.be/1q5oqp0iX4Q?t=710):

> It's ten years old and uses an import of the [RtAudio](https://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtaudio/) audio library that only supports ALSA, which means with a PulseAudio system, it can't access the sound device.

So I suppose the answer is: learn C++ audio programming with RtAudio and upgrade the library yourself.